Customtkinter ScrollableFrame Deletion not working
I was working one an application and wanted to create a page which asks the user to enter the location .
I am using customtkinter, for this I created a Frame "f2" and a label "l8" where label is just "please enter your location" and I wanted to create this effect where if u press on button "b5" with the text "CITY", it would create a scrollableFrame named "se1" which is inside a function "Scrollable1" , the scrollable frame is created just below the button city and would contain button with names of city (which i'll add later) and I also created another button "b6" (this is just a part of my project so the variable names are like this) with text "STATE" which on click would generate a scrollable Frame as well named "se2" which is inside a function called "Scrollable2" .
Further on, I wanted to create an effect where only one of the scrollable frame remains on screen , for ex : if I press city button then a scrollable frame should appear below it and then if I press state button the scrollable frame from city should dissappear and scrollable frame from state button should appear meaning only one of the scrollable frame should remain on screen . so I created a code for it which I have mentioned below :
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("610x600")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(fg_color="black")


def Scrollable1():
    global se1
    se1 = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(f2, )
    se1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    b5.configure(state="disabled")
    try:
        if se2 in globals():
            f2.destroy(se2)
    except:
        pass

def Scrollable2():
    global se2
    se2 = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(f2, )
    se2.grid(row=4, column=1)
    b6.configure(state="disabled")
    try:
        if se1 in globals():
            f2.destroy(se1)
    except:
        pass


global f2
global b5
global b6
f2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root, fg_color="black", width=600, height=585)
f2.grid(row=0, column=0)
l8 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(f2, text="Please select your Location", text_color="white", font=                                    ("Helvetica", 15))
l8.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20)
b5 = customtkinter.CTkButton(f2, text="CITY", text_color="white", fg_color="black", width=250,     height=30, border_width=1, border_color="white", hover_color="black", command=Scrollable1)
b5.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10)
b6 = customtkinter.CTkButton(f2, text="STATE", text_color="white", fg_color="black", width=250,     height=30, border_width=1, border_color="white", hover_color="black", command=Scrollable2)
b6.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)



root.mainloop()

However, when I run this it doesnt work can anyone tell me where I have done it wrong ??
would really appreciate it.

Note that se1 (or se2) refers to the internal frame inside an implicitly created Canvas widget which is inside an implicitly created outer Frame widget (referred by ._parent_frame).  To remove the scrollable frame widget, you need to destroy the outer frame widget instead:
def Scrollable1():
    global se1
    se1 = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(f2)
    se1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    b5.configure(state="disabled")
    try:
        # destroy the outer frame instead
        se2._parent_frame.destroy()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    # enable the "STATE" button
    b6.configure(state="normal")

def Scrollable2():
    global se2
    se2 = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(f2)
    se2.grid(row=4, column=1)
    b6.configure(state="disabled")
    try:
        # destroy the outer frame instead
        se1._parent_frame.destroy()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    # enable the "CITY" button
    b5.configure(state="normal")

